# How to keep track of amount of actions done in Todo app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mern

I am building a MERN stack todo app, I want to have a indicator where it shows how many todos I have and how many I have done. my todo in MongoDB, has 2 attributes (todo(action), status(true or false)) I am able to fetch the amount of todos, but I am not able to fetch how many have I completed, in other words how many of my todos have status true in mongodb.
As you can see in the code(I removed not necessary part) in useEffect I set the amount to the todos.length, which is the amount of todos I have, but how to see the amount of todos done I have no idea

```js
  const [todos, setTodos] = new useState([]);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");
  const [amountDone, setAmountDone] = useState(0);
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/")
      .then((res) => {
        setTodos(res.data);
       
       setAmount(todos.length)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [todos]);
 
   return (

      <div className="todo-list">
        {todos.map((todo) => {
          if (todo.status) {
            return (
              <div className="todo" key={todo._id}>
                <button onClick={() => handleStatus(todo)}>true</button>{" "}
                <p>{todo.todo}</p>
                <div className="todo-actions">
                  <Link to={`/update/${todo._id}`}>Edit</Link>
                  <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo._id)}>Delete</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <div className="todo" key={todo._id}>
                <button onClick={() => handleStatus(todo)}>false</button>{" "}
                <p>{todo.todo}</p>
                <div className="todo-actions">
                  <Link to={`/update/${todo._id}`}>Edit</Link>
                  <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo._id)}>Delete</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found a solution thanks to chatgbt) I don't know is this the most efficient but the solution goes this way
Add following two lines into useEffect

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/")
      .then((res) => {
        setTodos(res.data);
         // Count the number of completed todos
      const completedTodos = res.data.filter((todo) => todo.status);
      setAmountDone(completedTodos.length);

       setAmount(todos.length)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [todos]);
```